# Splitting the Primary partition in

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, data-warehouse, partitioning

On a table I have created a partition based on Year I have data from 2008 onwards
I have created following partitions 2008, 2009, 2010 and Primary.
Since primary has data for 2011 and 2012, I want to split the primary partition

I created a new file group for 2011. I ran the script for splitting the primary partition

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [PartScheme] NEXT USED [FG2011]
GO
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION PartFunction() split Range (20111231)
GO
```

after this the primary partition is getting split, but the data for the year 2011 is in primary partition and the data for the year is in 2011 partition.

```
partition_number    FileGroupName    value
1                    FG2008        20081231
2                    FG2009        20091231
3                    FG2010        20101231
4                    PRIMARY       20111231
5                    FG2011          NULL
```

I want the Partition for the current year that is 2012 to be in Primary. How can this be done?

Comment: was your partition function created using "RANGE LEFT" or "RANGE RIGHT"?  Also, what's the query you used to generate the result set...

Comment: It is using "Range Right" and regarding the Query to get Resultset is Good thats why i was able to display Result, but here i think the Result comes different regarding the Filegroup when we use Range " LEft or RIGHT"

Comment: can you update your post with the query you ran to get the result set you posted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script for the job:

```
alter partition function PF_MyFunction()  MERGE RANGE (20111231)
alter partition scheme PS_Myfunction next used [FG2011]
alter partition function PF_MyFunction()  SPLIT RANGE (20111231)
```

Here a script to check that your partition is actually on a different FG. Run it before and after.

```
SELECT 
     schema_name(c.schema_id)   [Schema_Name]
    ,object_name(a.object_id)   [Table_Name]
    ,a.name                     [Index_Name]
    ,a.type_desc                [Index_Type]
    ,d.Partition_Number         [Partition_Number]
    ,b.name                     [Logical_DataSpace Name or PS name]
    ,b.data_space_id            [Logical_DataSpaceID_PS_ID]
    ,f.name                     [Partition Function]
    ,f.function_id              [Partition Function ID]
    ,g.value                    [Partition Boundary Value]
    ,ISNULL (h.data_space_id, b.data_space_id) 
                                [Physiscal DataSpace ID]
    ,i.name                     [FileGroup Name]
    ,i.type_desc                [Physical Dataspace desc]

FROM (sys.indexes a inner join sys.tables c 
    on a.object_id = c.object_id) 
INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces b on a.data_space_id = b.data_space_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions d on d.object_id = a.object_id
LEFT JOIN sys.partition_schemes e on e.data_space_id = b.data_space_id
LEFT JOIN sys.partition_functions f on f.function_id = e.function_id
LEFT JOIN sys.partition_range_values g on g.function_id = f.function_id and g.boundary_id = d.partition_number

LEFT JOIN sys.destination_data_spaces h 
            on h.partition_scheme_id  = e.data_space_id AND h.destination_id = d.partition_number

INNER JOIN sys.data_spaces i on i.data_space_id = isnull (h.data_space_id, b.data_space_id)

WHERE c.name = 'MyTable'
```